# How to change reset password token expiration duration and length, in .net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have searched on how to change the duration of the reset password token and its length and I didn't find any helpful code to use, and here it is my final code that also not working for me.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
        }).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>            
            o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need custom implementation, these links should help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429485/create-shorter-tokens-with-small-lifespan-in-asp-net-core-identity https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/5436#issuecomment-373965907

Comment: Hi @MuhamedRaafat, As mathis1337 said, to change the token expired time, you could [change the email token lifespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#change-the-email-token-lifespan). But, for security it will generate an encrypted token in the email. I'm not suggesting you send the token as a plaintext (such as 4 digits). You could open the browser in the mobile and login the email and reset the password.

Comment: `I want to use it as API for mobile, so I only need 4 digits`, From your description, I suppose you want to reset the password with SMS, you could consider [enabling QR Code generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and use [Multi-factor authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score -1):

The default token lifespan of the Identity user tokens is one day. This section shows how to change the email token lifespan.

Add a custom `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>` and `DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions`:

```
public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser>
                                       : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options,
        ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger)
                                          : base(dataProtectionProvider, options, logger)
    {

    }
}
public class EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    public EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions()
    {
        Name = "EmailDataProtectorTokenProvider";
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
    }
}
```

Add the custom provider to the service container:

```
config.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmation",
            new TokenProviderDescriptor(
                typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>)));
        config.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";
      }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddTransient<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>();
```

This is from the microsoft docs. You can read it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Is this a custom class for generating a reset password token or a confirm email token ??

Comment: I want to use it as API for mobile, so I only need 4 digits, this code generates a long length token

Comment: Its for email tokens so its for any of them. Since you are using Microsoft identity model that's how they have  it outlined. As for the length its suppose to be long. Its a cryptographically generated token. Shortening them makes them insecure. If you want a shorter URL you can mask it behind a URL shortener or simply use an a href and put a cover on the link. You should read up the ms docs on their identity stuff. You'd find all this info.

Comment: If you don't care about email the link I posted in my answer also has how to change in application tokens too. So regardless it has the answer to your question. As for shortening that is a bad idea.